# Android Studio automatically generated name for Extract String Resource

Tags: android, android-studio

During previous projects in Android Studio, when I would trigger the Extract String Resource popup, it would automatically generate a resource name for me, but lately that field is always empty and I have to type one.

I can't seem to find any settings that would control this. Is this a feature that was removed or is it something I need to enable?

How can I get Android Studio to automatically generate a string resource name in that popup?

[image]

Comment: I never seen suggestion for java classes. This is only available for xml layouts.

Comment: I don;t think that there ever was auto-generated string res name. Probably you used some plugin

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko It's definitely not a plugin, because even my partner (who is new to Android Studio and doesn't have any plugins) has gotten it to happen for him. Evidence of that is that some of his extracted string resource names are literally 124 characters long and they are just a transform of the text value. (Obviously he shouldn't have used that default resource name, but it's still evidence of the automated behavior.)

Comment: @Khemraj I just tried it in an xml layout and it didn't happen there either.

Comment: @Kenny Wyland did you find any solution?

Comment: @MarsPeople No, it looks like Android Studio only generates the name for you when you're extracting the string from a layout file and it doesn't do it when you're doing it from code.

Comment: @KennyWyland yes it works on layout file string extracting, but didn't it working on "code files" in old releases of android studio? :/ As far as I remember it was working, they removed it in new releases :/

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin that extracts hardcoded strings, and also gives names automatically in generated string resources. Check it out on [github](https://github.com/it-objects/android-string-extractor-plugin), it might suit your needs.

Comment: I'm not talking about a separate plugin that will scan my project for hardcoded strings. I'm talking about the built-in Extract String Resource action.

Answer (score 0):

One setting that prevent background thread to run is AS power saver mode. 
If this is enable your AS will run very light but you will not see many of suggestions like extract string.

If you find this **Power saver mode enabled** then **disable it** by navigating to

> File > Uncheck power saver mode.

Restart AS and let all strings be processed by AS threads.

- Extract string suggestions are only available for `layouts.xml` not for java classes.